# How much does Six Sigma relate to space exploration?

Tags: measurement, risk-management, space-industry

[Six Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) allows industrial quality control at 99.99966% that is if you have some repeated processes you improve until you have a guarantee that only 0,00034% of all processes fail.

> A six sigma process is one in which 99.99966% of all opportunities to produce some feature of a part are statistically expected to be free of defects.

Is there some relation of this quality control system to space exploration and engineering? Or, which measurable quality level is currently common (that is, maybe some guys apply SixSigma, some guys measure quality in other ways)?

Comment: Apparently in the past it has been [a bit lower](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=vTWmDRoONM0C&pg=PT198&lpg=PT198&dq=feynman+99+44/#v=onepage&q=feynman%2099%2044%2F&f=false) at 99$\frac{44}{100}$%.

Comment: "Six Sigma" is a specific brand of quality control system. Or are you inquiring about any quality control system that aims at a failure rate of 0,00034%?

Comment: There was a management fad called Lean Six Sigma at JSC in the 2000s. Full of ridiculous nomenclature like "black belts", etc. Like all management fads, the working troops paid lip service to it when required, avoided it when possible.

Comment: J.Doe - are you asking what organisations (eg NASA, Space X) use 6-Sigma processes and measurement?

Comment: @RoryAlsop if there would be a relation inquired by this question, one could ask whether they do so, or similar, or plan to.

Comment: Can you edit the post then? Currently it makes little sense, as six sigma does not relate to space exploration at all. Space exploration organisations and teams may use six sigma processes - so that is the question you should ask.

Comment: Just a minor nit-pick, but standardized, formalized "quality control" systems are not intended to guarantee "high-quality" product. They are intented to give management _control_ of the quality of the product. If management wants to make a shitty product, then a quality control system supposedly can help them to ensure that the product will be _precisely_ and _consistently_ as shitty as they want it to be.

Comment: ^" to ensure that the product will be precisely and consistently as shitty as they want it to be." wonder how many shitty products have such a strategy behind them..

Comment: @OrganicMarble There are still people touting those credentials in the field. Still doesn't mean much as far as I can tell.

Comment: @J.Doe Most of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89675/discussion-on-question-by-j-doe-how-much-does-six-sigma-relate-to-space-explora).

Comment: @called2voyage there was a giant 1970s line printer at JSC that was a critical element in a software production process. It broke frequently and parts were hard to come by. A Lean Six Sigma study was kicked off which ran for months and produced an impressive stack of documents.  The answer was to replace the printer with a modern one. Their grasp of the obvious was impressive.

Comment: Six Sigma is still very much alive in the corporate world. It's basically a technique of project management or change management. It has some bizarre vocabulary but some solid concepts. For one, it formalizes the requirement of a sponsor in upper management who can give resources and authority to the team. Without that, they're powerless. For another, it formalizes the control phase, which tracks and evaluates the results after the changes have been made. In the middle is a process of defining requirements, eliminating non-requirements, assigning responsibilities, etc.

Comment: (Continued...) I don't know how it's used in space exploration, but I'd bet it is used because it's generic and a standard part of corporate and institutional culture.
I Googled around a little. Yep. Here's a blog post about Lean Six Sigma at NASA.
https://blogs.nasa.gov/Shanas-Blog/2008/08/29/post_1220024980633/
And there are other hits. So NASA has it, too. I pray they don't also have the Fish Philosophy.

Comment: @Greg that link brought back some awful memories. It's from the 2000s as I stated above. Probably NASA management is on a different fad now.